# jquery 1.9.1 - Tabs shown but not working and tab content fully shown

Tags: jquery, tabs

I've set up jquery tabs with the ui. Included js and css is there aswell as jquery is.

But as soon as I load the page the tabs are properly shown but in every content is the full content of each tab content on top of each other.

The code is exactly the same as shown in the jquery-ui documentation but not working.

Here my includes

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/includes/scripts/jquery/jqueryuicss/base/jquery-ui.css" />
```

The script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({ active: 0 });
    });
});
</script>
```

And the HTML

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1"><img src="/images/flaggen/Germany.gif" alt="Deutsch" border="0" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2"><img src="/images/flaggen/grossbritanien.gif" alt="Englisch" border="0" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3"><img src="/images/flaggen/russland.gif" alt="Russisch" border="0" /></a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <p>TEST Deutsch</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <p>TEST Englisch</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
<p>TEST Russisch</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Please help, thanks in advance

Bernhard

Comment: I just try your code and it work for me. Have you another CSS loaded in your page ?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for responding. Yes, there are other CSS files included but if I comment them out, it is the same. I've also tried the code in a naked website template loading nothing else and there it is the same. The tabs are well formated and clickable. But the content is fully shown on top of each other.

Comment: Just found the reason:
There was a baseHref tag in the header like
<base href="URLblabla">
If there is a baseHref the tabs won't work for some reason. I don't know why...just happy it works now and I can code the ajax part of it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Good day,

I had the same issue and it was resolved by using another jquery version (1.7.0 instead of 1.9.1).

Try replacing the JavaScript src
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
with
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js.

I hope this helps anyone that finds themselves in the same bind!
Have a great day!
-Mike